# Disable Xcode 6 built-in snippet?

Tags: xcode, code-snippets

Is there a way to disable certain built-in snippets of Xcode 6?

Specifically I find the *Core Data Fetch* snippet to be distracting and not useful (since I use `mogenerator` and the default snippet doesn't paste in the correct fetch that's optimal for it). Hence I'd like to disable just this particular snippet.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to edit Xcode's built-in snippets, indeed, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23700537/269108), though bear in mind that the changes can be lost when updating to a newer version of Xcode.

Specifically, as of **Xcode 6.3.1 (6D1002)**, the **Core Data Fetch** snippet can be found at **line 681** in the snippet file:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets
```